# Excel Structured Reference issues

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 separate tables (`FullOrders`, `ShortedOrders`), each with an `[Order Number]` column. `FullOrders` shows every order we've fulfilled and `ShortedOrders` show only orders that were not sent with all the product.

I've created a column in `FullOrders` called `[Short?]` and would like it to show a value of 1 if *any* `ShortedOrders[Order Number]` matches the `FullOrders[Order Number]` that sits on the same row as `FullOrders[Short?]`. Otherwise `FullOrders[Short?]` will show 0.

I've tried a few formulas and haven't found the right solution.

Formulas I've tried:

```
=IF(ShortedOrders[[#Data],[Order Number]]=FullOrder[[#Data],[Order Number]], 1, 0)

=IF(ShortedOrders[[#Headers],[Order Number]]=FullOrder[[#Headers],[Order Number]], 1, 0)

=IF(ShortedOrders[[#Data],[Order Number]]=FullOrder[[#Headers],[Order Number]], 1, 0)

=IF(ShortedOrders[[#Headers],[Order Number]]=FullOrder[[#Data],[Order Number]], 1, 0)

=IF(E2 = ShortedOrders[Order Number], 1, 0)

=IF([Order Number] = ShortedOrders[Order Number], 1, 0)

=IF(E2 = ShortedOrders[[#Data], [Order Number]], 1, 0)

=IF([Order Number] = ShortedOrders[[#Data], [Order Number]], 1, 0)
```

The results are a 0 for a while, and then `#VALUE` after it hits the last record in `ShortedOrders`.

An `IF` statement may not even be the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to this after further research. I needed to nest a `COUNTIF` for the comparison of the column to the cell.

```
=IF(COUNTIF(ShortedOrders[[#Data], [Order Number]],[Order Number])>0, 1, 0)
```